# L2 norm inequality problem

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFxMU.png)

Hello, I need help to understand the inequalities in the red rectangle. Is it a property of L2 norm that I miss ? Thank you

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

equation 1.5.2 state that:
$$
C \|e^{-\lambda \phi}(\partial_t+i\partial_x)w\| \geq \lambda^{1/2}\|e^{-\lambda \phi} w\| \tag{1}.
$$
Choose $w=\chi u$, with using (1) we get :
$$
\lambda^{1/2}\|e^{-\lambda \phi} \chi u\| \leq C \|e^{-\lambda \phi}(\partial_t+i\partial_x) (\chi u) \| \tag{2}
$$
you can either use Leibniz rule or definition(notation) of book :
$$
(\partial_t+i\partial_x) (\chi u) = [\partial_t+i\partial_x,\chi]u+\chi (\partial_t+i\partial_x) u \tag{3}
$$
so (2) becomes :
$$
C \|e^{-\lambda \phi}(\partial_t+i\partial_x) (\chi u) \| \leq \underbrace{C \|e^{-\lambda \phi} [\partial_t+i\partial_x,\chi]u+e^{-\lambda \phi} \chi (\partial_t+i\partial_x) u\|}_{C_1}
$$
use triangle inequality here :
$$
C_1 \leq C \|e^{-\lambda \phi} [\partial_t+i\partial_x,\chi]u\| + C \| e^{-\lambda \phi} \chi \underbrace{(\partial_t+i\partial_x) u}_{au}\| \\
= C \|e^{-\lambda \phi} [\partial_t+i\partial_x,\chi]u\| + C \| e^{-\lambda \phi} \chi au\| =: C_2 \tag{4}
$$
by definition of book (again comes from Leibniz rule), $ [\partial_t+i\partial_x,\chi]u = (\chi'_t+i\chi'_x)u$ . And since :
$$
\| fg\|_{L^2} \leq \|f\|_{L^{\infty}} \|g\|_{L^2}
$$
then put these 2 back into (4) :
$$
C_2 \leq  C \|e^{-\lambda \phi} (\chi'_t+i\chi'_x)u\| + C \|a\|_{L^{\infty}} \| e^{-\lambda \phi} \chi u\| .
$$
but we have a better bound, since $\chi=0$ outside of its support $\| e^{-\lambda \phi} \chi au\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R^n})}= \| e^{-\lambda \phi} \chi au\|_{L^2(\text{supp}\,\chi)}$ , so second term becomes :
$$
\|a\|_{L^{\infty}(\text{supp}\,\chi)} \| e^{-\lambda \phi} \chi u\|
$$